# how to create a prefix route in swagger

Tags: go, swagger

Usually the examples provided by swagger setup simple servers, where all the api calls for json functions are on the document root.
e.g. the famous "hello world" sits at "/hello"  .

I want to find a way to define a given prefix, so that can put the a specific api under this prefix. if the prefix would be "/api/2.0", the example api would become

```
/hello   --> /api/2.0/hello   # The prefix would be "/api/2.0"
/goodbye --> /api/2.0/goodbye #
```

in the end i want to keep this dynamic and really provide a commandline switch with some

```
server -prefix '/api/2.0'
```

and the server would use this for the api. Note that i can then also specify no prefix, and the system should fall back to "/hello" and "/goodbye".

Is this possible with the go-lang implementation of swagger (https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger)

Can somebody point me to an example / or give a short example?

**Addendum**:
I want to do this basically with a swagger 2.0 interface.
I learned now that it needs something like this:

```
http.Handle("/", middlewareOne(middlewareTwo(finalHandler)))
```

Basically the task is to leave the swagger generated "finalHandler" untouched (so it thinks still handles "only" /hello, or /goodbye). But the middleware would catch all traffic before the finalHandler. The "/api/2.0"  would be removed/transformed  (this what i am searching, how???) and the middleware would pass this to the finalhandler, which still believes that it serves /hello. I am not sure if the information that it runs "/api/2.0" is ever neeeded, but mabybe it should be added as context.

See
https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/blob/master/docs/use/middleware.md

Quirky solution, which seems to work.

```
func setupGlobalMiddleware(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
  prefix:="/api/2.0"
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, prefix) {
       r.URL.Path = r.URL.Path[len(prefix):]
    }
    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

I would rather prefer if would have access to the "handlers" map in the generated code, but it is not accessible. This way i could just "re-register" everything with a prefix. Maybe ther is a better solution?

Comment: In your swagger spec file, presumably `swagger.json`, set `basePath` field to `/api/2.0`

Comment: @har07  sorry, was to tired, did not see your comment. of course basePath is the static solution. just was searching for doing this by code, in order to avoid to regenerate (tested) code all the time. But if you add it as solution, it is at least 80%

Answer (score 0):

Simple example code. Enjoy.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)
type (
    API interface {
        Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
        Goodbye(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
    }
    API2 struct {}
    API3 struct {}
)

func main() {
    mux := httprouter.New()
    mux.GET("/api/:version/:command",API_HANDLER)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8091", mux))
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  HANDLERS
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
func API_HANDLER(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params){
    var hand API
    switch p.ByName("version") {
    case "2.0": hand = API2{}
    case "3.0": hand = API3{}
    default: hand = nil
    }
    switch p.ByName("command") {
        case "hello": hand.Hello(w,r)
        case "goodbye": hand.Goodbye(w,r)
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  API2 version
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
func (a API2) Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("[API2] Hello"))
}
func (a API2) Goodbye (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("[API2] Goodbye"))
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  API3 version
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
func (a API3) Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("[API3] Hello"))
}
func (a API3) Goodbye (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("[API3] Goodbye"))
}
```

Comment: HI Spouk, that gave me inspiration, where to look into. Thanks. But basically what swagger requires, that is what is understand now, is to build a Middleware which does something like http.Handle("/", middlewareOne(middlewareTwo(finalHandler)))      .    Found this, but still not a clue https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/blob/master/docs/use/middleware.md